# Oracle ODAC x64 bit issue with Append_values hint batch error mode not supported for this operation

Tags: c#, oracle, for-loop, odac

I am using x64 bit ODAC to connect to oracle 11g from .net webservice.
Code fails with: "error :ora-38910: batch mode not supported for this operation" when executing query with append_values hint. Is this hint supported by x64 bit oracle client , version 2.112.1.0. The x86 bit oracle client for same version works fine.

```
OracleParameter[] aryParams = null;
System.Text.StringBuilder SQlcols = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.Text.StringBuilder SQLvalues = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.Text.StringBuilder SQL = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
Int32 pNum = 1;

if (colFields.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (tblField fld in colFields.Values)
   {
       if (!fld.IsStaticValue)
        {
            fld.CleanUp();
            if (fld.ValueArray == null)
            {
                return false; // If no values were added to the arrays, exit function
            }

            if (aryParams == null)
            {
                aryParams = new OracleParameter[1];
            }
            else
            {
                OracleParameter[] aryParams2 = new OracleParameter[aryParams.Length + 1];
                Array.Copy(aryParams, aryParams2, aryParams.Length);
                aryParams = new OracleParameter[aryParams2.Length];
                Array.Copy(aryParams2, aryParams, aryParams.Length);
            }

            aryParams[aryParams.GetUpperBound(0)] = new OracleParameter("", fld.DataType, ParameterDirection.Input);
            aryParams[aryParams.GetUpperBound(0)].Value = fld.ValueArray;
            SQLvalues.Append(":");
            SQLvalues.Append(pNum);
            SQLvalues.Append(",");  //create csv of param numbers.
            pNum += 1; //increment param number
        }
        else
        {
            if (fld.StaticValue is string)
            {
                SQLvalues.Append("'");
                SQLvalues.Append(fld.StaticValue);
                SQLvalues.Append("',"); //create csv of param numbers.
            }
            else
            {
                SQLvalues.Append(fld.StaticValue);
                SQLvalues.Append(",");
                //create csv of param numbers.
            }
        }
        SQlcols.Append(fld.FieldName);
        SQlcols.Append(",");
        //create csv of field names
    }
    // Trim off trailing commas
    SQlcols = SQlcols.Remove(SQlcols.Length - 1, 1);
    SQLvalues = SQLvalues.Remove(SQLvalues.Length - 1, 1);
    SQL.Append("INSERT /*+ append_values */ INTO ");
    // SQL.Append("INSERT INTO ");
    SQL.Append(this._tblName);
    SQL.Append(" (");
    SQL.Append(SQlcols.ToString());
    SQL.Append(") VALUES (");
    SQL.Append(SQLvalues.ToString());
    SQL.Append(")");
    try
    {


        if (dat.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL.ToString(), false, aryParams) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        // clean up
       Int32 i;
        for (i = 0; i <= aryParams.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            aryParams[i].Dispose();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: For fast batch insert to Oracle we are using append_values hint , here is the line of code thats failing:

 SQL.Append("INSERT /*+ append_values */ INTO ");  

1)On a x64 2.112.3.0 system above code works.

2)on a x86 2.112.1.0 and x64 2.112.1.0  system above code works.

3)on a x64 2.112.1.0 system on azure above code does not work.

Could this be an issue with x64 bit version of 2.112.1.0 , this batch mode is not supported or is there
any specific settings we need to use?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting it into comment - and again provide the code and the insert statement.

Comment: Some time ago I had the same issue but in Perl. My workaround was to insert all values into a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE (where `/*+ append_values */` has almost no effect) and then copy the data by `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM MY_TEMP_TABLE`. My requirement was to insert app. 4000 rows every(!) second

Comment: so you are saying oracle version or bit-ness has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I don't know, I never tested with 32-bit Perl

Comment: we actually do not want to change the code since it works with other versions of oracle, only failing with 64 bit of  2.112.1.0.

Comment: Are you sure you need the [APPEND_VALUES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#BABFIHGA) hint? According to my understanding it has an effect only for `FORALL ... INSERT` command or when you bind array as parameter value. I don't think this is the case because this would require an `aryParams[aryParams.GetUpperBound(0)].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;` I assume.